# Applying Bayes' theorem to Sleeping Beauty

Tags: logic, epistemology, probability

Suppose we believe the "thirder" position of the [Sleeping Beauty Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_beauty_problem). That is, we believe that `P(Heads | Waking up) = 1/3`.

Applying Bayes' theorem, we get

`P(Heads | Waking up) = P(Waking up | Heads) * P(Heads) / P(Waking up)`

By the definition of the problem, `P(Waking up | Heads) = 1`, and similarly `P(Waking up) = 1` since it is just the marginal over heads and tails.

This leaves us with `P(Heads | Waking up) = P(Heads) = 1/3`. So does that mean the thirder position implies that the *prior* probability of getting heads is 1/3? I.e. that even before the coin is tossed, we should assign a probability of 1/3 to heads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here seems to be that in order to do probability, you need to
know what space you're sampling from, and by construction, Sleeping Beauty
requires you to pay attention to that space.  There are two "intuitive"
spaces, and if you mix both, you end up confused.  Niel de Beaudrap has
already said as much, but given the amount of confusion expressed over this
"problem", I'd like to try being more explicit:

What "really" happens is this:

```
p=1/2    heads    awaken
p=1/2    tails    awaken    awaken
```

The funny thing about this is that you get two outcomes from one of the
branches.  This not infrequently happens in probability and statistics,
and it's no problem at all, but you have to decide what to do about it.

The Sleeping Beauty problem is typically formulated as Miss Beauty essentially
conducting an experiment each time she is woken up.  (Maybe you'll give her
a cookie if she's right.)  So half the time you get one experiment, half the
time you get two, and by construction in the problem you're supposed to lump
all of these together.  (If you had an army of Sleeping Beauties and you 
were tallying all the answers, this is what you'd want to do.)

So now we have three `awaken`s in our sample space:

```
heads-awaken   tails-awaken-1   tails-awaken-2
```

which are all identical.  So if we do your calculation:

```
P(H|awaken) = P(awaken|H)*P(H)/P(awaken) = 1*(1/3)/1 = 1/3
```

Wait, what was that?

```
P(H) = 1/3
```

That's pretty weird--but look, we didn't have to go through the calcuation to
find that.  We have a sample space that *by construction* has heads only one
time out of three (cleverly constructed from a process that has 50% heads!).
So this is exactly right: the prior probability of heads is 1/3.

And Miss Beauty and everyone else would agree on this in advance of the
experiment ever being run (at least if they were up on their statistics).

Alternatively, if the formulation is such that there actually *is* an implicit
difference between the different awakenings (e.g. because the last one is
part of Miss Beauty's permanent experience, or because if she's right once and
wrong once on the tails branch you'd want to only give her half a cookie, and you don't want to break cookies, so you only ask her one of the two times on the tails branch), then she
(and everyone else) should perhaps do a different calculation:

```
p=1/2    heads    awaken
p=1/2    tails
     p=1/4        awaken
     p=1/4                   awaken
```

The logic here is that if you're on the tails branch and you wake up, 50%
of the time you'll be on the first instance, and 50% of the time you'll be
on the second.  In this case, you can calculate things like

```
p(H|awaken#1) = p(awaken#1|H)*p(H)/p(awaken#1) = 1*(1/2)/(3/4) = 2/3
```

meaning that if you know you're in the midst of the experiment and it's the first time you woke up, there's a 2/3 chance you're on the heads branch.  (`p(H|awaken#2) = 0`, and `p(H) = 1/2` by the construction of this sample space.)

This is actually a more flexible framework to use--it is just as true as the
other one; it's just a different formulation suited for calculating different
things.  The key is recognizing how the sample space maps onto what may have
actually happened; if your sample space doesn't match the question you're
asking, you'll get the wrong answer.

For example, if Miss Beauty wants to maximize the number of cookies she's
awarded, and she gets one per correct guess, she will reason:

```
// I can pick only one option: H or T
// I will gain no information later so I may as well pick now

E(cookies) = sum(p(cookies)*#cookies)
If I pick H:
  p=1/2  right!         1 cookie
  p=1/2  wrong, wrong!  no cookie
  E(cookies) = (1/2 * 1  +  1/2 * 0) = (1/2 + 0) = 1/2
If I pick T:
  p=1/2  wrong!         no cookie
  p=1/2  right, right!  2 cookies
  E(cookies) = (1/2 * 0 + 1/2 * 2) = (0 + 1) = 1
```

Double the payoff if I pick `T`, even though I think `P(T) = 0.5`.

The real problem comes when one mixes the two sample spaces.  First, one thinks
that of *course* the three events are indistiguishable by construction, so
that `p(H|awaken)` = 1/3.  And of *course* a coin is fair, so `p(H)` = 1/2.
And then `p(awaken|H)` = 1 and `p(awaken)=` and `1/3 != 1/2` and...what the
heck?

Know the sample space, stick to it, and probability will make sense, even if
you are Sleeping Beauty.

[Note: [see also my chat transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7645/discussion-between-rex-kerr-and-xodarap) with Xoxarap.]

Answer (score 7):

1. Whether or not the coin has been tossed, the probability is just a model of how you expect events to turn out, or to have turned out, based on the information you have. Without having information about the result of the coin, it does not matter whether or not it has been flipped yet. The probabilistic model which assigns probabilities based on different amounts of information remains the same, and so is agnostic of time, in the same way that Newton's equations predict the same behaviour for an apple that is dropped from a height of 1m in similar conditions both for yesterday and tomorrow.
2. Probabilities are best assigned relative to one's experience of the world. In the Sleeping Beauty problem, the princess' experience of the world is biased by the sleeping drug. Although an undrugged observer may experience the coin as being fair, Sleeping Beauty's experience of the frequencies of the coin are different.

   At issue is the fact that Sleeping Beauty experiences the events of `heads` and `tails` with different frequencies relative to a control observer. Without additional information, Sleeping Beauty could rationally assign different probabilities to the outcomes of the coin, because we are deliberately skewing her experiences. Furthermore, while Sleeping Beauty knows we are skewing her experiences, this does not affect the experiences she will have as a result of the skewing. She could rationally infer that *we* perceive the coin to be fair, and also that *she* would perceive the coin to be unfair. Thus, even before engaging in the experiment she could assign a prior probability of 1/3 to `heads`, at least for her own purposes.

   Sleeping Beauty simply experiences a different probabilistic ensemble to ourselves, and so obtains a different frequency, in a manner not totally different to how different observers moving at different speeds will perceive sounds to be at different pitches due to the Doppler Effect. And similarly to shifting pitches of sounds, we can obtain a unifying probabilistic model, which does not assign a definite probability to the event `heads`, but which describes what probability each agent could rationally ascribe to the event depending on what ensemble their conscious experiences will be subject to.

Comment: "Sleeping Beauty could rationally assign different probabilities to the outcomes of the coin, because we are deliberately skewing her experiences" - but the usage of Bayes' theorem shows that her experiences don't actually skew her probability (i.e. her posterior equals her prior).

Comment: It is not her experience that skews the results, as I have noted in point #1. It is how her experiences will be structured. If Sleeping Beauty knows the nature of the experiment, she knows that she will be experiencing the skewed ensemble, and therefore should attribute a different prior than we would for what she will experience.

Comment: Let us agree that, before knowing about the experiment, she assigns `p = 1/2`. Now she goes through the experiment, and at the end of it believes `p = 1/3`. At what point did her beliefs change? Was it when they told her she was going to undergo the experiment?

Comment: @Xodarap - If she's any good at statistics, yes, kind of.  Her beliefs would change from "p = 1/2 for a fair coin flip" to "the just-woken-up me on average will experience p = 1/(1+n) chance of heads if they put me to sleep n times if it's tails".

Comment: @Rex: Fine, `P(Heads | Something) = 1 / (1+n)`. What is that something? It can't be "being informed about the experiment" because that falls to the same argument in my original question.

Comment: @Xodarap - Let's turn this around.  Can you _define_ what a probability is?  The entire sleeping beauty "problem" seems like a case of talking and thinking about something that one doesn't actually properly define or understand.  Once you say, "By p = ___, I mean _____", the whole problem (to me at least) grows vastly less mysterious.  All the confusion ends up being, "Oh!  I was thinking X but talking about Y, no wonder it doesn't add up!"

Comment: @Rex: Suppose for simplicity we say `P(X=k)=y` means "as the number of experiments tends towards infinity, the fraction in which X=k tends to y". It seems to me we still have `P(Waking up)=1` etc.?

Comment: @Xodarap - Okay, what defines "the experiment"?  Is Sleeping Beauty conducting an experiment every time she wakes up?

Comment: @Rex: Sure, that's fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7645/discussion-between-rex-kerr-and-xodarap)

Answer (score 3):

I take it that the thirder *doesn't* believe that `P(Heads|Sleeping Beauty waking up at all)=1/3` (although this is suggested/implied by your further argument), but rather that `the/an awake Sleeping Beauty's P(Heads|being awake at the/a moment of evaluation) should be 1/3`. That would imply that the premise of your (further) argument is false ("That is, [...]"). Therefore, everything that *follows* may be [valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity), but isn't [sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness).

Comment: Hmmm, but isn't a premise of the problem that she can't differentiate between "waking up at all" and "waking up at instant X"?

Comment: Please note that my answer doesn't address the Sleeping Beauty problem, but only _your_ question/argument, which, in my opinion, doesn't properly represent the thirder's position from its outset. And, regarding your comment, she _can_ differentiate (admittedly in a somewhat abstract way) between "waking up at all" and "waking up at instant X": she knows that she's certain about the former, and she knows that she's uncertain about the latter. Therefore, those are two _distinct_ conditionals (according to the thirder).

Comment: Example. You know that _somebody_ will win tomorrow's lottery, but you're not sure whether it will be _you_. In your logic that implies that you can't "differentiate" between those events and therefore you might as well assume that **(A) you _will_ win the lottery** (and therefore start buying champagne today). This logic fails because your logic _also_ can't "differentiate" between "somebody winning the lottery" and "somebody _else_ will win the lottery", implying that you might as well assume that **(not-A) you will _not_ win the lottery**.

Comment: That's [epistemic logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-epistemic/) for you: knowing something X to be true is distinct from something X is true.

Comment: Gugg: Yes, I think a premise of the problem is that she can't differentiate between "I woke up once" and "I woke up twice" - in your analogy, she can't differentiate between "someone won the lottery" and "I won the lottery".

Comment: @Xodarap I suggest you can make the problem much more graspable if you'd rewrite it such that if 'Heads' then woken up only once and if 'Tails' then woken up 10,000 consecutive days. However, I don't care about the problem. I only care about you implicitly or explicitly misrepresenting the thirder in your question.

Comment: Gugg: I understand the intuition behind the thirder position, even without making it extreme. I just don't understand how to rectify it with Bayes' theorem. It would be appreciated if you could specify where exactly I'm misrepresenting people - the only claim I've made of thirders (that I know) is that they believe `P(Heads | Waking up) = 1/3`.

Comment: @Xodarap Exactly, right there! 1) Because, in my opinion, the `Waking up` here isn't the same `Waking up` you use later in, e.g., `P(Waking up) = 1`. So, you seem to reinterpret the thirder's position (wrongly). 2) Also, the thirder doesn't believe that `P(Heads | Waking up) = 1/3`; instead he believes that _Sleeping Beauty_ should hold that probabilistic belief (although more exactly expressed as in my original answer).

Comment: @Xodarap I see that this issue might have originated from the Wikipedia page, which bluntly states "The thirder position argues that the probability of heads is 1/3." In my opinion, this is a bit sloppy and possibly confusing, but the context makes things clear. "Any time Sleeping Beauty is wakened and interviewed, she is asked, "What is your belief now for the proposition that the coin landed heads?"" The thirder gives his answer for _that_ question.

Comment: @Xodarap And where I said "his" in my last comment, please read "Sleeping Beauty's". :)

Comment: Sleeping beauty has some evidence which causes her to believe that `P(Heads | Evidence) = 1/3` while still maintaining that the marginal `P(Heads)` is 1/2. What is that evidence?

Comment: @Xodarap Presumably _according to the thirder_, the "evidence" is that 1) she is part of the experiment and 2) that she finds herself awake to make the evaluation. On an aside: What would her hypothetical evaluation be if she'd find herself _asleep_ (on Tuesday)? `P(Heads | Asleep) = 1`. That's where the "missing" probability "disappeared" to, since (1/4)*1+(3/4)*(1/3)=1/2. Are we clear now? :)

Comment: completely agree that `P(Heads | Asleep *on tuesday*)=1`, but I think a premise of the argument is that she doesn't know what day it is. It still seems to me that `P(Being part of the experiment & being awake | Heads) = 1` etc., so the original problem remains.

Comment: @Xodarap You're wrong. If she's asleep and knows that and could somehow still evaluate, she would conclude both `Tuesday` and `Heads`. To (hopefully, although I doubt it) clarify: Imagine that Sleeping Beauty has an advisor who is always awake but has no memory beyond today, although he knows about the experiment, and he doesn't know what day it is. He always advises her on the probability, even if he observes her to be asleep. What would his advice be? What would his advice be when he observes her to be asleep? What would his advice be when he observes her to be awake?

Comment: @Xodarap And, although this isn't relevant to my point, "she doesn't know what day it is" _isn't_ among the premises of the problem.